# Understanding need to place .go files under pkg folder?

Tags: go

It's very often I see .go files committed to pkg folder, like here https://github.com/kubernetes/apiserver what particular reason doing that vs using vendor folder for 3rdparty dependencies or commit your own code into src dir?

Comment: Where are you very often seeing .go files committed in pkg directories? It's not common, it just happens to be the name of a directory in the kubernetes source.

Comment: yes, thats was part of my question, I was wondering if kuberenetes team has particular reason to name it like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clarify further.

- The `pkg` folder on that repo you linked is where they put the packages they wrote. Reason? well they need to put them somewhere, they chose `pkg`.
- You use `vendor` folder when you don't want future changes to 3rd party packages you've used possibly make your program unstable, in that case you "vendor" those 3rd party packages. So you don't put your own packages in `vendor` folder for obvious reasons.
- Which `src`? `$GOPATH/src`? you can do it! probably, I haven't test it. But you can only have one project in that case, and that's the project that you've placed there.

Comment: thanks for reply, I just confused when they using 'reserved' folder name to store sources but actually it possible to use any other folder name here. Any particular reason for that?

Comment: No. No particular reason. You're right, they could use any other folder name, but "they" decided to name that folder pkg. Maybe because they thought it's more familiar to the eyes of other go developers, indicating that folder is where the *.go files can be found. But this isn't the common practice. Usually developers leave everything in the project root. e.g. Look up labstack/echo project.

Answer (score 0):

There's **no need** to have your project's files under a `pkg` folder. And there's no need to have a `pkg` folder, inside your project, in the first place.

`pkg` **is not** a "reserved" folder name, at least not in the context of your project.

`vendor`, on the other hand, has special significance for the Go compiler and is inteded to hold code that was written as part of a separate project, e.g. 3rd party packages. Therefore it makes no sense, for the linked project, to move the code they have under `pkg` into `vendor`.

If you want to understand why kubernetes or other projects decided to use `pkg` you would best be served by enquiring through those projects' communication channels (mailing lists, irc, social media, etc).